# import icons dynamically react fontawesome

Tags: reactjs, icons, font-awesome

I am using FontawesomeIcon in a react js project and the names of the icons are coming from the database. I want to import the icons coming from the database from @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons dynamically

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faImage} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export class Features extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="features" className="text-center">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="features-listing">
            {this.props.data.map((item, index) => (
              <div key={`${index}`}>
                {" "}
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={item.icon} />
                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Features;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In App.js, you can import all the icons, as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56255226/3238392), like this:

```
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import * as Icons from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const iconList = Object.keys(Icons)
  .filter((key) => key !== 'fas' && key !== 'prefix')
  .map((icon) => Icons[icon]);

library.add(...iconList);
```

Then, inside components, only import the FontAwesomeIcon and use them:

```
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

<FontAwesomeIcon icon="times" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The icons names I want to use are unknown, they are coming from a request to the database, so this way will not work

Comment: @AmmarIsmaeel Please check my edited post on how you can import all those icons

Comment: Thx, It worked, though I did not like the idea of importing all icons, it seems its the only solution

Comment: @AmmarIsmaeel It would be more problematic to import them one by one dynamically, because the process is asynchronous. It shouldn't be a problem if you import them all at the beginning.

Comment: I believe there are +26k icons. It's doubtful your database is referencing all of them. So maybe query the unique list of icon name, and create a subset or a kit. This should dramatically scale back the icon load.

Answer (score 15):

There is actually a better way without having to iterate all icons (@Andrei Rosu's solution), you can export the whole **brand** and **solid** packages:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

// This exports the whole icon packs for Brand and Solid.
library.add(fab, fas)
```

and to use them:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'apple']} /> // any icon from Brand.
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'coffee']} /> // any icon from Solid.
```

Answer (score 3):

this can be done without importing all icons using react's dynamic imports. just replace the import string with whatever dynamic variable you need.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import React from 'react'

function example(){
  const Icon = React.lazy(() => import('@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faEnvelope').then(({definition}) => ({default: () => <FontAwesomeIcon icon={definition} />})));
    
  return <React.Suspense><Icon /></React.Suspense>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need to import all icons. You can import some icons in your `app.js` like:

```js
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faAngleRight, faArrowRight ... } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'; 

library.add(faAngleRight, faArrowRight, ...)
```

Then use it like:

```js
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fal fa-angle-right" />
```

or for dynamic use to any component (like button with icon) as prop:

```js
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} />
```

Answer (score -1):

Just simply add the `Fontawesome` CDN to your `HTML Header` and use any icon you want,

it would be something like this in react:

```html
    <i className={object.ico}><i/>
```

`Object.ico` should be a string containing the icon name like `far fa-xyz`

Comment: But I want to use the @fortawesome/react-fontawesome package, I do not want to use any cdn and place it in the html, Its better to have packages in your project